# How to categorise NSLog into Error, Warnings, Message and Fault type in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-simulator

We are developing iOS app. We want to create Custom Class of **NSLog** which will defines four type of message iOS App system like

```
1. Error
2. Fault
3. Info message
4. Warnings
```

Is there some Apple standard documentation to create such type of message definition or How do create special case for our App log messages?

Comment: use swiftyBeaver https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver

Comment: We want to create in Objective C not in swift @SandeepBhandari

Comment: check here https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-customize-nslog-for-easier-debugging--mobile-19066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible to accomplish with  `NSLog()`.

If you want to do use log levels, you should use `os_log()` from libtrace on iOS 10+ or ASL on earlier versions.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging

Comment: Do you any example for the above-mentioned answer? @Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia